# How do I read this formula?

Tags: computational-mathematics

It's been a long time since my college days, so I need some help for something that is likely pretty simple to most of you.

In the book *Factory Physics*, there is a formula for Service Level stated as follows:

$$Service Level = P\{CycleTime \le LeadTime\}$$

I'm not sure how to read or interpret the formula. Can you help me out in digesting it?

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They define service level as a number between $0$ and $1$, indeed a probability.
The service level  equals the probability that your cycle time is less or equal to your lead time.

Somehow an interesting definition: one could imagine an ideal factory, where they deliver $1$ second earlier with probability $0.5$, or $1$ $\mathbf{year}$ later again with probability $0.5$.

Such factory would have the same service level metric of a competitor, delivering $1$ second earlier with probability $0.5$, or $1$ second later again with probability $0.5$.

I would still call the second one...

Comment: Both Kenny Lau and An aedonist answered my question, and I thank them both. However, An aedonist added an interesting comment on the logic employed in this calculation, and the comment is (in my opinion) very worthy of consideration.

Answer (score 0):

The "service level" is equal to the probability that the "cycle time" is less than or equal to the "lead time".